# nexus - unable to query xz extension on the rest api

Tags: nexus3

I used to be able to query `maven.extension=xz`:

```
http://nexus-server.com:8081/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?&repository=maven-releases&maven.baseVersion=1.1.7&maven.groupId=com.xxx&maven.artifactId=xxx&maven.extension=xz
```

After upgrading to nexus 3.30.0 it returns a 404.

I did not find any permission to set this, guessing it was introduced for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

had to change the extension from xz to tar.xz and bingo bango it works.